# angular4 no input were found in config file tsconfig.ts in npm json2excel

Tags: angular

I'm downloading package for convert between JSON to excel file call is json2excel
but I found an error in file tsconfig.ts

### show error msg is:

> No inputs were found in config file c:/Users/Name/Desktop/my-first-app/node_modules/js2excel/tsconfig.json. Specified 'include' paths were '["src/**/*.ts"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["lib"].

Comment: Did you make any changes to this file before?

Comment: no the file content is :{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}

Comment: can you help me to fix it ?

Comment: i try to add  this code to file but not work also :  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*"
  ],

Comment: I think this is only available as a server-side package. It also had a peer dependency on `fs`. You could expose an API from node which would receive the json as a request payload. You could then create an excel there and then send the download link to the client.